# Telerik Html5 Report Viewer cannot pass parameter for sql stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, telerik, report, viewer

I trying show report in asp.net mvc.

Telerik Report v8.0.14.225

Procedur , javascript , report desing screenshot attached in [telerik forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/procedure-or-function-'expects-parameter-'@resid'-which-was-not-supplied)

here i can't post image no reputation.

When call without parameters all work fine.

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var _date1 = $("#date1").data("kendoDatePicker").value();
    var _date2 = $("#date2").data("kendoDatePicker").value();
    $("#reportViewer1")
        .telerik_ReportViewer({
            viewMode:"PRINT_PREVIEW",
            serviceUrl: "/api/reports/",
            templateUrl: '/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate.html',
            persistSession:true,
            reportSource: {
                report: "Cloud.Report.Revenue, Cloud.Report",
                parameters: {
                    ResId: @ViewData["ResId"],
                    date1: _date1,
                    date2: _date2
                }
            }
        });
});
```